# cantidad de veces que puedo crear dependiendo de una receta

Tags: php, sql, matemáticas, lógica

Me gustaría saber la forma de saber las cantidades de veces que puedo crear de una receta dependiendo de la cantidad de un inventario.

Para crear una objeto, este requiere de una receta. Tengo una tabla donde guardo una receta.

```
/*Tabla de receta*/
--------------------------------------
| Producto | Cantidad  | product_id   |
-----------|-----------|--------------|
| Item 1.1 |    100    |  1           |  
| Item 1.2 |    200    |  1           |  
| Item 1.3 |    300    |  1           |  
|----------|-----------|--------------|
```

Ejemplo si voy a crear el producto 1, y de este producto quiero crear 3, en mi inventario tengo las siguientes cantidades.

```
/*Tabla inventario*/
   --------------------------------------
    | Producto | Cantidad  | code_user   |
    -----------|-----------|-------------|
    | Item 1.1 |    500    |  10001      |  
    | Item 1.2 |    400    |  10001      |  
    | Item 1.3 |    600    |  10001      |  
    |----------|-----------|-------------|
```

De acuerdo a mi inventario solo podria crear 2 productos.

Aqui mi codigo:

```
  $query_receta = "SELECT  FROM table_receta WHERE product_id='$id'";
        $result_o    = mysqli_query($ConexionMYSQL, $query_receta);
        /*Recorremos la receta*/
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_o)) {
          $receta_cantidad = $row['Cantidad'];
          $item_producto   = $row['Producto'];
          /*Busco producto de mi inventario*/
          $query_stock = "SELECT SUM(Cantidad) FROM table_inventario 
WHERE Producto ='$item_producto' AND Code='$code'  GROUP BY Producto ";

            $result_stock   = mysqli_query($ConexionMYSQL, $query_stock);
            $resultStock    = mysqli_fetch_row($result_stock);
            $cantidad_stock = $resultStock[0];

        }
```

Que logica deberia aplicar para saber la cantidad de veces que crear ese producto.

Comment: No trabajo con PHP pero deberias recorrer cada fila y realizar la division Cantidad Stock / Cantidad necesaria, y si es mayor o igual a cero el resto deberias tener un resultado de para cuanto te alcanza tu stock para hacer la receta.

Comment: @MoteCL creo que el resultado lo quieres obtener a nivel de consulta, pero a lo mejor seria mas simple si realizas una operación en un jquery o en un javascript mandas los datos requeridos, realizas la operación, te regresa el resultado y es lo que mandas a imprimir o mostrar en pantalla, ya si requieres guardar el resultado quizás lo podría enviar a otra tabla, así tendrías un historial de recetas elaboradas

Answer (score 1):

Partiendo de tu ejemplo, lo más sencillo sería hacer una búsqueda en base de datos que cruce receta y cantidades de las que dispone el usuario o cocinero, tomando como referencia el producto más limitante para la receta, es decir, aquel que menos veces podemos utilizar, siendo el número de productos (NPRODUCTOS en el ejemplo) el que puedo fabricar con este. De este modo sólo necesitas recorrer un resultado.

Pongo un ejemplo a continuación:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `receta` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cant` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `prod_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `receta` (`id`, `cant`, `prod_id`) VALUES
  ('1', '100', '1'),
  ('2', '200', '1'),
  ('3', '300', '1');

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stock` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cant` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `stock` (`id`, `cant`, `user_id`) VALUES
  ('1', '400', '23'),
  ('2', '500', '23'),
  ('3', '600', '23');
```

---

**Query #1**
Selecciono el producto limitante para la receta 1 para el usuario 23. Si tuviera más recetas en la tabla filtraría por `user_id` y `prod_id`.

```
SELECT *, S.`cant`/R.`cant` AS NPRODUCTOS
FROM `stock` S 
LEFT JOIN `receta` R ON R.`id` = S.`id`
WHERE S.user_id=23
ORDER BY NPRODUCTOS ASC LIMIT 1;

| id  | cant | user_id | id  | cant | prod_id | NPRODUCTOS |
| --- | ---- | ------- | --- | ---- | ------- | ---------- |
| 3   | 600  | 23      | 3   | 300  | 1       | 2          |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)